# Django template return all files in section

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Here my problem, The user can add Sections, in the section he can add documents, what I would like to do it's to return all documents added in section I can't figure it out which way is the best to filter by section:

Here my model for the Documents :

```
class Document(models.Model):
    """
    Staff of the hospital center services
    """

    # ATTRIBUTES
    label = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Intitulé'
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Description',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    document = models.FileField(
        verbose_name='Document'
    )
    section = models.ForeignKey(
        'espace_documentaire.EspaceDocumentaire',
        verbose_name="Espace Documentaire",
        related_name="documents",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    dedicated_page = models.ForeignKey(
        "pages.Pages",
        verbose_name="Page",
        related_name="documents",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    division = models.ForeignKey(
        "services.Division",
        verbose_name="Pôle",
        related_name="documents",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    order = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name="Ordre d'affichage",
        default=0
    )

    # TRACE
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="date de création",
        auto_now=True
    )
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="date de modification",
        auto_now=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section
```

Here my Model for the Sections :

```
class EspaceDocumentaire(models.Model):

    # ATTRIBUTES
    section = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Nom de la section'
    )
    colorsection = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Couleur de la section'
    )
    order = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name="Ordre d'affichage",
        default=0
    )
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        'documents.Document',
        verbose_name="Document",
        related_name="documents",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section
```

Here my template :

```
{% for ed in espace_documentaire %}
    <div class="dpt-toggle" id="{{ ed.pk }}">
        <h3 class="toggle-title">{{ed.section}}</h3>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <div class="tabs clearfix">
            {% for document in documents %}
                {% if document.section == ed.section %}
                    <h1>{{ document.label }}</h1>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would filter a single section documents in a view:

```
def section_documents(request, pk):
    section = EspaceDocumentaire.objects.get(pk=pk)
    documents = section.documents.all() # using related name you set in your model
    return render(request, 'section_documents.html', {'section': section, 'documents': documents})
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for document in documents %}
    {{ document }} 
{% endfor %}
```

**OR** you could also just use the related name in the template like this:

```
def sections_and_documents(request):
    sections = EspaceDocumentaire.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'sections_and_documents.html', {'sections': sections)
```

and in the template:

```
{% for section in sections %}
    {{ section }}
    {% for document in section.documents.all %}
        {{ document }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```